# How to make commands parameters case insensitive?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So basically I want to make so the commands parameters will be case insensitive. For example: ?role [member] [role]. So, I don't have to type the full name or the same capitalization of the member and role name. Is it really possible? Because I've tried Dyno bot, and it seems like it's possible. I've tried this code but it doesn't work:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("d", "D"), intents=intents, help_command=None, case_insensitive=True)
```

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxBVF.png), I didn't type the member name fully and the role name with the same capitalization.

Comment: Do you just want the command arguments case insensitive or the entire command case insensitive? Ex. `!say True` and `!saY True`

Comment: @Ceres `!saY True` works if I have `case_insensitive` on, but I want to make the parameters/arguments case insenstive. Look at the imgur link I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for members *(like in the image)*, you can specify the parameter to be a member object, then you can give the name, mention the member or give the id of the member.

An example would be:

```py
@commands.command(name="userinfo")
async def userinfo(self, ctx, Member : discord.Member):
    # Do your stuff
```

Comment: I did this, what I want is to not enter the full member name and to not always type the same capitalization as the member name/role name (so the bot will choose the closest member/role with the name I typed like in the image).

Answer (score 0):

Lower the parameters using `.lower()`

```
@commands.command()
async def role(self, ctx, Member : discord.Member, Role):
     role = Role.lower()
```

If you want the first letter capitalized then do this:

```
@commands.command()
async def role(self, ctx, Member : discord.Member, Role):
     role = Role.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use discord's converter's

```
@commands.command()
async def role(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None, Role: discord.role = None):
     if role is None or member is None:
         await ctx.send('you need to specify a member and a role')
     else:
        if role in member.roles():
           await member.remove_role(role)
        else:
           await member.add_role(role)
```

### References:

- [Converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=converters#discord-converters)
- [Role converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=role%20converter#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter)
- [Member converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=role%20converter#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter)
- [roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.roles)

Comment: I've tried your code but it's still not working, I want to not enter the full member name and to not always type the same capitalization as the member name/role name (so the bot will choose the closest member/role with the name I typed like in the image) and my bot doesn't use cogs. Is it possible?

Comment: If discord.py's converter isn't working, you have to make your own converter for your case. [Read more about custom converters here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=converter#advanced-converters). I can't think of any other way to get role from a partial name